# Clojure Iterating over a list of hash maps

Tags: list, clojure, hashmap, sequence

I get an error "Don't know how to create ISeq from" from the following code.  Can anyone tell me why this is not a proper sequence?

```
(defn hash-map-list []                                                                                                                 
  (map (fn [component]                                                                                                                 
      {:name component})                                                                                                            
      '("Jim" "Bill" "Carrie")))                                                                                                      

(first hash-map-list)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you simply forgot to **call** your function :)

```
(first (hash-map-list))
{:name "Jim"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`hash-map-list` is a function. It isn't a list of hash-maps. If you call the function, your code will work.

```
(first (hash-map-list))
```